# page layout not working in html/css

Tags: css, html, iframe

I have a problem trying to move div's on the page based on the screen size..

I have got my pages (code as per below) displaying the width correctly but can't seem to get the height correct when the user re-sizes the page.

What I am trying to do is..

- have a header that is displayed across the top
- a page on the left which will have a menu in it
- a page to the right that will display the page text
- a footer across the bottom

[image: sample of what I am tring to do]

My pages looks like this below:

index.htm:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding-bottom:10px;   /* Height of the footer */
    } 

    #topsection{
    background: #EAEAEA;
    height: 90px; /*Height of top section*/
    }
</style>


    <!-- top -->
    <div id="topsection">
        <div>
            This is the top
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Left side -->
    <div ID="left" STYLE="width:260px; left:0px; height:90%; float:left;">
        <iframe src="test.htm" NAME="menu" width="270px" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>

    <!-- right side -->
    <div ID="right" STYLE="height:90%; left:0px; float:left;">
        <iframe src="test1.htm" NAME="right" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>

    <!-- footer -->
    <div ID="foot" STYLE="height:10%; left:0px; top:90%; float:left;">
        <iframe src="foot.htm" NAME="footer" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
```

test.htm:

```
<body bgcolor="#808080">
```

test1.htm:

```
<body bgcolor="#88888888">
right side text
```

foot.htm:

```
<body bgcolor="#9999999">
This is a footer
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Header:

```
#topsection{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Your footer:

```
#foot{
    position:absolute;
}
```

you should use absolute I think

Here is some more info about the position 'tag' in css

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 1):

do this for top bar and footer.
hope might work in your case.

```
   #topsection{
       position:fixed;
................ 
        }
    #foot{
position:fixed;
................ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you ak for. [Fixed header and footer](http://limpid.nl/lab/css/fixed/header-and-footer)